# Como puedo arreglar este error al momento de seleccionar un input salgan las opciones

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

> Este es el codigo que tengo pero quiero que aparezca para elegir estas
> opciones, no se donde este el error

````
<option value="<?php echo $medicine->id . '*' . $medicine->name; ?>"
<?php echo 'data-frequency="' . $prescription_medicine_extended[1] ; ?> selected="selected">
=set_value('instruction')?>
<option>Tomar 1 al Día x 3 Días</option>
<option>Tomar 1 al Día x 7 Días</option>
<option>Tomar 1 c/4 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
<option>Tomar 1 c/6 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
<option>Tomar 1 c/8 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
</select>    
<?php echo $medicine->name;?>
 </option>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Estás cerrando la etiqueta  antes de agregar las opciones de instrucción, para solucionar tu error debes cambiarlo

```
<select name="medicine" id="medicine" class="form-control">
    <option value="<?php echo $medicine->id . '*' . $medicine->name; ?>" 
    <?php echo 'data-frequency="' . $prescription_medicine_extended[1] . '"'; ?> selected="selected">
        <?php echo set_value('instruction'); ?>
        <?php echo $medicine->name;?>

        <option value="1">Tomar 1 al Día x 3 Días</option>
        <option value="2">Tomar 1 al Día x 7 Días</option>
        <option value="3">Tomar 1 c/4 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
        <option value="4">Tomar 1 c/6 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
        <option value="5">Tomar 1 c/8 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
    </option>
</select>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos